# Virtual Forms vs Ajax POST

Tags: ajax

Ajax can't do cross-domain post due to the same-origin policy.  But, if we use Ajax to dynamic create a virtual form and do a cross-domain post, then the browser allows it.

Aren't they doing the same thing?  Why does the browser allow one but not the other?

Answer (score 0):

Ajax can - it's called [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) (Padded JSON).  jQuery has this built into it's ajax object

```
$.ajax({
url:'http://www.otherdomain.com',
crossDomain:true,
...
});
```

Comment: In order to use jsonp, the target server for the cross-domain post needs to support it.  I'm referring to a situation where I have no control of the target server.  For example, in order to transact with PayPal, I'm creating a virtual form on the fly and posting the data.  The alternative is to do a server relay (browser -> my own server -> paypal server).  I'm just curious why using virtual forms post works but not ajax post in this case.